# How do I use the bloomberg API to get FX data in a html site?

Tags: bloomberg

I am new to the bloomberg API so forgive me if this is silly but I am creating a html website on a mac and I want to simply fill a div with some data from bloomberg e.g. the current value of the EURUSD.

How can this be done? Is this what the bloomberg API is for?

Answer (score 3):

This is something that would typically be forbidden by the license - data obtained from the Bloomberg API can generally not be redistributed.

Plus (you might know that) the Bloomberg API is publicly available but to be able to receive actual data through the API, you need to subscribe to Bloomberg, which is a payable service.

There are probably better (and less expensive) ways to get EUR.USD rates.

Answer (score 1):

The API is for this, but the licensing is typically not. You can use the server mode and try to communicate with a Bloomber Server (paid component) and ask for licensing to redist the data. Your problem here is not technical but legal

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a Bloomberg account, you can get an idea of how this is done using the [Bloomberg API Emulator](http://bemu.codeplex.com/).  It works and looks just like the Bloomberg API, but it doesn't require an account to use.  It doesn't return real data, but you can use it to learn how to request data from the Bloomberg API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: This does not answer the question - it is asking for **real** data.

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  I will do that in the future.  And assylias, I disagree that my post does not answer the question.  The poster asks _How can this be done?_ in reference to requesting market data using the Bloomberg API.  Not only can this be done, but given the context of the question, it seems the poster has no Bloomberg account.  With the Bloomberg API Emulator (disclaimer: I wrote it), user852974 can learn how to make this market data request without requiring a Bloomberg account.

Answer (score 0):

From a 10-minute read of the [Developer's Guide](http://www.openbloomberg.com/files/2012/03/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf) at http://www.openbloomberg.com/, it looks like you might be able to use it to get current foreign exchange rates.  The Developer's Guide gives coding examples in Java, .NET, C++, and C.